# How to define Django model datefield

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am new in python django, i am creating app model and wants to define a field(date of birth) to input date from user form but unable to understand how to define date field in model so that i can capture the date(date of birth) using form.

Here is model

```
# Create your models here.

class funder(models,Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    user_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    user_dob = models.DateField('none' = true)
    user_address = models.TextField()
    user_status = models.PositiveIntegerField(default='1')
```

thanks

Comment: Argument  names are never in quotation marks and AFAIR the name was `null`, not `none`.

Answer (score 1):

Your model should be like below:

```py
# Create your models here.

class funder(models,Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    user_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    user_dob = models.DateField(null=true, blank=True)
    user_address = models.TextField()
    user_status = models.PositiveIntegerField(default='1')
```

`null=True` allows the field to be null in DB, and `blank=True` allows the field can be kept unfilled in the Forms (UI).

For more info you can go through [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField)

Answer (score 0):

#### Here I created a mini project on your requirement...

### models.py

```
class funder(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    user_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    user_dob = models.DateField()
    user_address = models.TextField()
    user_status = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1
```

)

### views.py

```
def HomeView(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    user_name = request.POST.get('user_name')
    user_mobile = request.POST.get('user_mobile')
    user_dob = request.POST.get('user_dob')
    user_address = request.POST.get('user_address')
    user_status = request.POST.get('user_status')
    funder.objects.create(
      user_name = user_name,
      user_mobile = user_mobile,
      user_dob = user_dob,
      user_address = user_address,
      user_status = user_status,
    )
  return render(request,'index.html')
```

### HTML code

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>Html Form</h3>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-5">
      <form method="POST" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="mb-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control mt-3" placeholder="Username" name="user_name">
          <input type="email" class="form-control mt-3" placeholder="E-Mail" name="user_mobile">
          <input type="date" class="form-control mt-3" placeholder="" name="user_dob">
          <textarea class="form-control mt-3" placeholder="Full address" name="user_address" cols="58" rows="5"></textarea>
          <input type="number" class="form-control mt-3" placeholder="Status" name="user_status">
        </div>
        
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Browser Output

[image]

[image]

[image]